# Two 50-point bounties at once?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I found a question in need of an answer, so I went to post a bounty of 50. The lowest option available was 100. Is this because I have another 50-point bounty happening simultaneously?

Comment: It’s hard to know for sure without sharing the question. One possibility is that you’ve previously bountied the 100-point question. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/320588

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is the question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/303814/247274)

While I posted an answer is hopes of bringing some resolution to an old question, I am not happy with the speculative nature of my answer, so I wanted a definitive answer.

Because I had answered, however, the bounty had to be at least 100.

> [If you have already answered the question before, the minimum bounty offer is 100.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/320588)